# error Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, element

I get an error when I run the program (vue3 + elements plus), but I don't know what's wrong with it. please help me.

Here is the error description and picture:

> 56:23  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (11:23)

[image]

---

[enter link description here](https://element-plus.run/#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)

---

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "vueui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "element-plus": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Place a comma after rules { }

Comment: @Krausladen this would make the JSON invalid.

Comment: You're getting an ESLint error reported. Probably the code builds and works just fine. Seems like you have not configured ESLint properly to work with TypeScript.

Comment: You might want to add and configure [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) in your project.

Answer (score 6):

In the current configuration, `eslint` cannot deal with TypeScript. The following steps enable TypeScript support.

- Run `npm install --save-dev @vue/eslint-config-typescript`
- Adapt the ESLint config:

  - Remove `"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"` from the `parserOptions`
  - Add `"@vue/typescript/recommended"` to the `extends` key

Based on your file above, it would look like this:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {},
  "rules": {}
}
```

Depending on your ESLint version, the installation of `@vue/eslint-config-typescript` might result in a dependency conflict. With ESLint < 9 you'll have to install `@vue/eslint-config-typescript@10`

Answer (score 0):

If Code Works Then You need to configure esLint if it throw an error then u need to place correctlly place it between {}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

My issue was caused by `find`. Vue error message is not help full

```
 <p v-if="clients" class="text-sm text-gray-400">
     No open or available details for 
    {{ clients.find((c: IClient) => c.id === selectedValue)[0]}}
 </p>
```

I made a mistake `find` will return `IClient` object not an array

Solution: Double check your code

```
 <p v-if="clients" class="text-sm text-gray-400">
         No open or available details for 
        {{ clients.find((c: IClient) => c.id === selectedValue)?.company }}
     </p>
```